# how to edit my main site collection?

Tags: sharepoint-foundation, document-library, master-page

I have created a site collection from the portal, I am not able to edit the page.
If i edit the page and click on save button, it shows the error message which is shown below:
[image]

I have checked the permission level, master page, everything is fine and clear but it still shows the error. But I am able to edit the subsite which lies inside the root site. What i have to do to fix this issue?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do the following:

1)  In Central Administration, go to Application Management->SharePoint Site Management->Site collection quotas and locks.  Once you have arrived, select the correct application and site collection, and you will have the opportunity to view and set the lock status of the collection (it most likely will be set to "Read-only", and you'll want to move that radio button to "Not locked").

2)  Fire up stsadm and issue the following command:

`stsadm -o setsitelock -url http://myportalsitecollection -lock none`

Comment: It is already in "NotLocked" status only, now what i have to do?

Comment: Did you fire the stsadm command as well?

Comment: yes.but the site remains the same error. i cannot able to edit and save.and also i restarted the server, but still it shows the same error.

Comment: are you using Pages Library? Please try to create a page in another library and check if it permits!

Comment: varun: This error existing for this site only. this site is main site collection, but the subsite from this site is not having this issue. i have done what you told now and also i checked the user permission level also, its working fine. i cannot able to predict the error.

Comment: In Screenshot i see you are also displaying documents on that page. Please follow these steps for that document library. http://dizzyonsharepoint.wordpress.com/2011/12/13/this-item-cannot-be-updated-because-it-is-locked-as-read-only/

Comment: varun  will you come to chat saro23988@gmail.com

Comment: Invited you.. :)